# Android: Center Text in programmatically added Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add a button programmatically in a custom view implementation. App is API 15+.
Here I am facing issue with button text not getting centered. It sounds trivial, but it is not working. Below is code in question. output is

[image: submit button]

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
mSubmit = new Button(mContext);
mSubmit.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
mSubmit.setText("Submit");
mSubmit.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.headertxt));
addView(mSubmit, params);
```

Comment: mSubmit.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

Answer (score 3):

Set equal padding for all sides of your button:

*for example:*

```
 myButton.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
```

Before:

[image: Before]

After adding our padding:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`addContentView` worked for me!

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
mSubmit = new Button(mContext);
mSubmit.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
mSubmit.setText("Submit");
mSubmit.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.headertxt));
addContentView(mSubmit, params);
```

Comment: this is a custom view. there is no addContentView call available in a custom view.

Answer (score -2):

It's not centered vertically, so try

```
mSubmit.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

Could also be some custom background for the button that's not correctly set up -- it's not very clear from the image.

And note : The gravity you set on the layout params is a completely different thing than the gravity you set on the button.